# In unity why getting error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on CameraScript?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

The error started once i deleted from the Hierarchy the AIThirdPersonController.
Now i have Main Camera and ThirdPersonController.

I have Main Camera in the Inspector i added a Camera Script.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour {


    public Transform TargetLookAt;

    public float Distance = 5.0f;
    public float DistanceMin = 3.0f;
    public float DistanceMax = 10.0f;

    private float mouseX = 0.0f;
    private float mouseY = 0.0f;
    private float startingDistance = 0.0f;    
    private float desiredDistance = 0.0f;

    public float X_MouseSensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float Y_MouseSensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float MouseWheelSensitivity = 5.0f;
    public float Y_MinLimit = -40.0f;
    public float Y_MaxLimit = 80.0f;

    public float DistanceSmooth = 0.05f;    
    private float velocityDistance = 0.0f;    
    private Vector3 desiredPosition = Vector3.zero;

    public float X_Smooth = 0.05f;
    public float Y_Smooth = 0.1f;
    private float velX = 0.0f;
    private float velY = 0.0f;
    private float velZ = 0.0f;
    private Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;

    CursorLockMode wantedMode;    


    void  Start (){
        Distance = Mathf.Clamp(Distance, DistanceMin, DistanceMax);
        startingDistance = Distance;
        Reset();
        SetCursorState();
        OnGUI();

    }

    void Update(){
    }

    void  FixedUpdate (){
        if (TargetLookAt == null)
            return;

        HandlePlayerInput();

        CalculateDesiredPosition();

        UpdatePosition();
    }

    void  HandlePlayerInput (){
        float deadZone= 0.01f; // mousewheel deadZone

        //if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        //{
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * X_MouseSensitivity;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Y_MouseSensitivity;
        //}

        // this is where the mouseY is limited - Helper script
        mouseY = ClampAngle(mouseY, Y_MinLimit, Y_MaxLimit);

        // get Mouse Wheel Input
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < -deadZone || Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > deadZone)
        {
            desiredDistance = Mathf.Clamp(Distance - (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * MouseWheelSensitivity), 
                DistanceMin, DistanceMax);
        }
    }

    void  CalculateDesiredPosition (){
        // Evaluate distance
        Distance = Mathf.SmoothDamp(Distance, desiredDistance, ref velocityDistance, DistanceSmooth);

        // Calculate desired position -> Note : mouse inputs reversed to align to WorldSpace Axis
        desiredPosition = CalculatePosition(mouseY, mouseX, Distance);
    }

    Vector3  CalculatePosition ( float rotationX ,   float rotationY ,   float distance  ){
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 0, -distance);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, rotationY, 0);
        return TargetLookAt.position + (rotation * direction);
    }

    void  UpdatePosition (){
        float posX= Mathf.SmoothDamp(position.x, desiredPosition.x, ref velX, X_Smooth);
        float posY= Mathf.SmoothDamp(position.y, desiredPosition.y, ref velY, Y_Smooth);
        float posZ= Mathf.SmoothDamp(position.z, desiredPosition.z, ref velZ, X_Smooth);
        position = new Vector3(posX, posY, posZ);

        transform.position = position;

        transform.LookAt(TargetLookAt);
    }

    void  Reset (){
        mouseX = 0;
        mouseY = 10;
        Distance = startingDistance;
        desiredDistance = Distance;
    }

    float ClampAngle ( float angle ,   float min ,   float max  ){
        while (angle < -360 || angle > 360)
        {
            if (angle < -360)
                angle += 360;
            if (angle > 360)
                angle -= 360;
        }

        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }

    // Apply requested cursor state
    void SetCursorState ()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = wantedMode;
        // Hide cursor when locking
        Cursor.visible = (CursorLockMode.Locked != wantedMode);
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginVertical ();
        // Release cursor on escape keypress
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape))
            Cursor.lockState = wantedMode = CursorLockMode.None;

        switch (Cursor.lockState) {
        case CursorLockMode.None:
            GUILayout.Label ("Cursor is normal");
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Lock cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Confine cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            break;
        case CursorLockMode.Confined:
            GUILayout.Label ("Cursor is confined");
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Lock cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Release cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.None;
            break;
        case CursorLockMode.Locked:
            GUILayout.Label ("Cursor is locked");
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Unlock cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.None;
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Confine cursor"))
                wantedMode = CursorLockMode.Confined;
            break;
        }

        GUILayout.EndVertical ();

        SetCursorState ();
    }
}
```

The error is on the line:

```
GUILayout.BeginVertical ();
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.BeginLayoutGroup (UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options, System.Type layoutType) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:252)
UnityEngine.GUILayout.BeginVertical (UnityEngine.GUIContent content, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayout.cs:308)
UnityEngine.GUILayout.BeginVertical (UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayout.cs:296)
CameraScript.OnGUI () (at Assets/My Scripts/CameraScript.cs:135)
CameraScript.Start () (at Assets/My Scripts/CameraScript.cs:43)
```

In the Main Camera Inspector in the Camera Script area the Target look At is set to ThirdPersonController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are calling the `OnGUI()` function from the `Start()` function. Don't do that.

```
void Start()
{
    Distance = Mathf.Clamp(Distance, DistanceMin, DistanceMax);
    startingDistance = Distance;
    Reset();
    SetCursorState();
    OnGUI();///--------------------->DON'T DO THIS!
}
```

The `OnGUI()` function is Unity GUI callback function and is automatically called by Unity to create GUI. Remove that line of code from your `Start()` function and your problem should be gone. If you have anything to initiate from the `Start()` function, create a new function that will do that.

That new function should **not** be named `OnGUI()` and must not contain any GUI functions such as `GUILayout.BeginVertical();` `GUILayout.EndVertical();`, `GUILayout.Button("Confine cursor")`.

**Notice**:

*`OnGUI()` function should not be used in your game. You should **only** use that as a testing tool to test a functionality in your game, in the Editor **only**. It is very costly and slow when used in an actual game. You can learn about the new Unity UI you should be using [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).*

Answer (score 0):

As your stack trace shows that you have the source, step through it in a debugger to work out what is null. It's likely that you have not configured GUILayout correctly.

[Apparently](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-guilayout-problem.318067/), OnGUI and GUILayout are "legacy" code anyway, so it may be worth looking into whatever the newer alternative is.